# On using 'in' and 'of'

Tags: prepositions, writing-style

In the following sentence, what is most appropriate: ***in 1977*** or ***of 1977***?

> For Oprah, April Fools' Day in 1977 wasn't funny at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. April Fools' Day represents a date, and no preposition is required at all.

> 22 June 1980 was a good day.
>   For Oprah, Christmas Day 1979 brought many gifts.
>   For Oprah, April Fools' Day 1977 wasn't funny at all.

If you are discussing the year *in toto* and drawing attention to a particular day, then either *in* or *of* will work. *In* is probably more likely, but I suspect that a corpus search for this particular construction won't be particularly easy. However, in that case, the year will be understood and can be omitted altogether  (and the preposition with it).

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Leach. I am discussing the year to draw the attention to a particular day.